# response to thank you after helping

Tags: conversation

I kept a door for somebody to pass and he said: "thank you". What should I say in response? I said: "no problem!". But I am not sure my response was the best one.

Comment: I'm not sure there is a "best" response, but there was nothing wrong with yours. You should say where you are though - the range of sensible responses varies between English-speaking countries.

Comment: We could not say that is the best one, but that`s okay, I think. I think you'd better  use "happy to help" or "welcome".

Comment: There isn't a 'standard' response to 'thank you' in English (like _prego_ in Italian, for example). "You're welcome" is as good as anything

Comment: One of the pleasures of being a polite person is to vary the response - 'you're welcome', 'please don't mention it', 'not at all', etc. I really hate 'no problem'. You don't really have to say anything out loud; you can just smile if you want.

Comment: ... I've never liked "No problem" either, as it sounds evaluatory. And _any_ response can have a you've-given-so-I-must-give feel (and that can lead to excess).

Comment: You can overthink ritual politeness, like the "After you, Cecil" "No, after _you_, Claude" characters on a British radio comedy programme in the 1940s.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to be polite, you can try "My pleasure" in response.

Answer (score 0):

Safest/best will always be, "You're welcome" - like bread and butter, they go together. It doesn't have to drug out, said quickly is good.

However, if you 'tune in' to listening to what others do, you will hear other responses that are just as natural, and the tone used. And upbeat "Sure!" works just as well.

Last night at the convenience store, someone opened the door for me. I said, "Thank you, Sir!" and he said, "You bet!"

I always try to make eye contact when saying "Thank you", even if for a second. It's pretty cool and helps me not take kindnesses for granted.

If you do a search for 'responses to "Thank you"', there are many, with varying opinions. Try different ones and see what feels right. Not recognizing the gesture at all is the only bad option. EDIT: Like Michael Harvey said, a nod or smile is also a response.

Comment: +1 for eye contact.